# Keyboard shortcut to quicksave Tomb Raider II

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, games

Usually, with the Aspyr Media version of Tomb Raider II on MacOS (newest version), you save game with

> Fn+F5

and load game with

> Fn+F6

on the Macbook Pro 2016.

However, this frustratingly overlaps with the voice control when you press

> Fn

Is there a way to set a shortcut key which, when in the game, will shortcut Fn+F5 (for example, just pressing F5)? The BetterTouchTool I am using doesn't appear to be recognized within the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate the Fn key you would have to toggle the global control for F-Keys, in the Keyboard Control Panel

[image]

Comment: This has worked indeed. Now I can save the game much easier. Thank you.